# Copy files with match prefix AND suffix with shell script

Tags: shell, cp

I have a directory with files such as

```
aaaXXXbbb.png
aaaYYYccc.png
xxxAAAyyy.png
yyyAAAxxx.png
```

Now I want to copy all files with prefix 'aaa' and suffix '.png' to a new directory with shell script, let say 2 files 'aaaXXXbbb.png' and 'aaaYYYccc.png'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a one liner:

```
grep '^aaa.*\.png$' list.txt | xargs -I '{}' cp '{}' destination_dir/
```

`grep` is looking for 'aaa' at the start of the line followed by zero or more characters and ending with '.png'. It then pipes that as a list of arguments to `cp` which moves them to 'destination_dir'

If you are in the directory of the files you can just `cp` them with:

```
cp aaa*.png destination_dir
```

Comment: Thank you very much, if I'm in a directory instead of getting a list.txt and all files which is in the list.txt is in the current dir, what would be the right command to do the job?

Comment: That's not what you asked for ;) If you need to copy the files in the current directory you would do something similar with `cp`

Comment: @user1794469 That is what he asked for. The question states that he is trying to find and copy files. There's no need to put the filenames into a file and then grep for them.

Comment: @NasirRiley he edited the question.

Comment: @user1794469 And it still states that he is looking to copy files. The only way for `grep` to apply would be the put the names into a text file before using `grep` which isn't necessary when `find` is already available.

Comment: Thank you! My appreciation to both of you.

Answer (score 7):

```
cp aaa*.png /some/destdir
```

This would match all filenames starting with the string `aaa` and ending in the string `.png` and copy them all to the directory `/some/destdir`.  The `*` would match any number of any characters in the middle of the name.

This would fail if you had many thousands of files matching the pattern, since the generated list would be too long.

In that case, use something like the following loop:

```
for name in aaa*.png; do
    cp "$name" /some/destdir
done
```

This would copy the files one by one.

A more efficient method for many thousands of files would be (using GNU `cp` with its `-t` option):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'aaa*.png' -exec cp -t /some/destdir {} +
```

Or (without GNU `cp`):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'aaa*.png' -exec sh -c 'cp "$@" /some/destdir' sh {} +
```

This last `find` command would find all regular files (`-type f`) under the current directory (only, due to `-maxdepth 1`) whose names matches the pattern `aaa*.png`, and for batches of these it would call a short in-line shell script.  The short in-line shell script would simply copy the files in the current batch (which would be a reasonable and managable number of files) to the destination directory.

More on `find` using `-exec`: [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Answer (score 0):

With `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name aaa\*.png -exec cp {} destination \;
```

`.` indicates the current directory.

`-maxdepth 1` tells it to only look in the current directory

`type -f` tells it to look for files

`-name aaa\*.png` indicates files beginning with `aaa` and ending in `.png`

`-exec cp {} destination \;` copies the files into the directory called `destination`.

My environment requires me to escape the `*` with a `\`. Yours may not require this so you may be able to just use `aaa*.png`